# VC++ .Net Clr/Safe and Clr/Pure

Tags: visual-c++, clr, compiler-options

In VC++ .Net, The What does the Clr/Safe (`/clr:safe`) and Clr/Pure (`/clr:pure`) means?

Comment: Additional information from DUMPBIN's documentation: "The /clr:pure and /clr:safe compiler options are deprecated in Visual Studio 2015 and unsupported in Visual Studio 2017 and later. Code that must be "pure" or "safe" should be ported to C#." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/clrheader?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 3):

From the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx):

> **/clr:pure** Produces a Microsoft
>   Intermediate Language (MSIL)-only
>   output file that has no native
>   executable code. However, it can
>   contain native types compiled to MSIL.
>
> **/clr:safe** Produces an MSIL-only (no
>   native executable code), verifiable
>   output file. /clr:safe enables
>   verification diagnostics (PEVerify
>   Tool (Peverify.exe)).

Comment: Does this prevent me from accessing DirectX or win32 code from within my c++ cli assembly?

Comment: I would also like to know if these are just type-checking or if these place a flag in the header that identifies them as pure or safe?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's enough information. It seemed from the other answer that it was just type checking. It seems from [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx) that it's a lot more than that.

> When `/clr` (not `/clr:pure` or `/clr:safe`) is used and `__clrcall` is not used, taking the address of a function always returns the address of the native entry point function. When `__clrcall` is used, the native entry point function is not created, so you get the address of the managed function, not an entry point thunk function. For more information, see Double Thunking.
>
> `/clr` (Common Language Runtime Compilation) implies that all functions and function pointers are `__clrcall` and the compiler will not permit a function inside the compiland to be marked anything other than `__clrcall`. When /clr:pure is used, `__clrcall` can only be specified on function pointers and external declarations.